# Is there a good tutorial or resource available on SolrJ?

Tags: solr, solrj

I have been using SolrJ, the Java client for Apache Solr server, at my work. But it is disheartening to see that there are hardly any resources available online for it.  Even the wiki on the parent site is kind of a "noob" guide !

There are few blogs like these which would get you started with SolrJ but no advanced stuff.

I would love to see if there are folks who have worked with SolrJ and could help me out by giving some pointers to valuable resources around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beyond the [SolrJ usage notes on the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj?highlight=%28%28Solrj%29%29) I don't think there really is, although it's more than enough to get you running.

There are also the unit tests, which aren't really a "tutorial", but still useful.

Also, the general Solr documentation is helpful as well, since SolrJ is basically just a thin wrapper client.

Comment: I think this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ is helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

SolrJ is not having full Documentation. But you can refer some basic example to understand SolrJ simple [SolrJ Example](http://www.learnhosting.org/solr-and-solrj/)

Comment: @Lernkurve: Link updated now.